# Hibernate Search Portioned requests

Tags: spring-boot, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I'm creating a web site with REST API, Angular 2 on front-end and Spring on back-end. And there is infinite scroll when I look through request result. And I'm using full text search to find matches of my request. My question is how to create portioned requests in my Hibernate Search? If possible, introduce some examples of code.

Peace of code that I use for fulltext search

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class HibernateSearch {
@PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public List<Manual> fulltextSearching(String keyword){
    if(keyword.equals("")) return Collections.emptyList();
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
            org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Manual.class).get();
    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
            fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(createQuery(qb, keyword), Manual.class);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Manual> result =  jpaQuery.getResultList();
    return result;
  }

private  org.apache.lucene.search.Query createQuery(QueryBuilder qb, String keyword){
    return    qb
            .keyword()
            .onFields("name", "introduction", "user.username", "tags.name")
            .matching(keyword)
            .createQuery();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use paging, as provided by the Java Persistence API:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class HibernateSearch {
@PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public List<Manual> fulltextSearching(String keyword, int offset, int limit){
    if(keyword.equals("")) return Collections.emptyList();
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
            org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Manual.class).get();
    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
            fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(createQuery(qb, keyword), Manual.class);

    // ADDED CODE HERE
    jpaQuery.setFirstResult(offset);
    jpaQuery.setMaxResults(limit);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Manual> result =  jpaQuery.getResultList();
    return result;
  }

private  org.apache.lucene.search.Query createQuery(QueryBuilder qb, String keyword){
    return    qb
            .keyword()
            .onFields("name", "introduction", "user.username", "tags.name")
            .matching(keyword)
            .createQuery();
  }


}
```

Results are sorted by relevance by default, so there's no need to add a sort.

Comment: To obtain the second page, do you need to create a new `FullTextQuery` or can you reuse `jpaQuery` object?

Comment: @nuoritoveri You can reuse the query as long as your EntityManager is open.

Comment: @YoannRodière Does it mean you can just set increase the value using `setFirstResult(resultIndex)` and then call `list()` again? If I do I always get the same first page of results (I ensured I increase `resultIndex` correctly).

Comment: @nuoritoveri If you're using Elasticsearch, you might be affected by this bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2843 . It's been fixed in the latest release (5.8.0.CR1), you might want to give it a try. Make sure to also upgrade Hibernate ORM to 5.2.3 or later if you're coming from Hibernate Search 5.6.